# Unable to get images to load, htaccess fix not working

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I am re-writing the question because it should be easier to solve now that i did a fresh install with lessons learned.

The issue is that directories like credearn.org/news or /login do not work.  It needs to redirect "missing" directories to format like: credearn.org/public/index.php/news

When I add a rewrite rule, it either causes 500 errors in the homepage rewrite rules or it doesnt do anything lol

Here is my htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteBase "/"

 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
 RewriteRule ^(comments)($|/) - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
 # RewriteRule ^/news$ /public/index.php/news$ [NC]
</IfModule>
```

I commented out my latest failed test.
The idea is that I think just ONE line should fix all directories and not break the images.

Comment: In your `RewriteRule`, shouldn't `\\.` be `\.`? In other words, you want to match a literal `.`, not a literal single backslash.

Comment: That worked but there are so many issues in this script that I decided to do a fresh install.  I am re-writing the OP question because it should be much more simple to solve I think

Comment: The URL path RewriteRule matches against never starts with a `/`, when configured in .htaccess, that has already been stripped off at this point. As for any 500s you get, you need to go and check the error log first of all.